# Linq checking that no value matches

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that has the following columns:

```
| FruitID | UserID | FruitName | ....
```

I'm looking to create a query that returns a boolean:  true if none of the user's fruits are called a certain name and that returns false if the name is already in the table

This is what I have:.

```
using (MyDC TheDC = new MyDC())
{
    return TheDC.TheTable
                   .Where(l => l.UserID == TheUserID)
                   .Select(l => l.FruitName == TheFruitName ).Any();
}
```

What do I need to do to make this query work?

Comment: does it not already work?  what's wrong with it?

Comment: Where are you comparing the `FruitName` ?

Comment: @SamIam: it needs to return false if it finds one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.Any` itself,and I think your query works the opposite and you need a `!` also before return to return false if there is any.

```
using (MyDC TheDC = new MyDC())
{
    return !TheDC.TheTable
                   .Any(l => l.UserID == TheUserID && l.LeadsheetName == TheLeadsheetName);           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Any` with no parameters returns whether the given sequence has any elements in it, regardless of what the elements are. To make it do what you seem to expect it to (see if any `true`s were returned from your select), you would need to add a condition to it:

```
.Select(l => l.FruitName == TheFruitName).Any(b => b)
```

Of course, instead of selecting booleans and then checking them, you should just do the check directly:

```
.Any(l => l.FruitName == TheFruitName)
```

According to your description, this returns the opposite of what you want though: you want it to return `true` if it is *not* in the table. Two ways to write that are "NOT ANY TRUE" or "ALL FALSE":

NOT ANY TRUE (notice the `!` at the beginning of the expression):

```
!TheDC.TheTable
    .Where(l => l.UserID == TheUserID)
    .Any(l => l.FruitName == TheFruitName)
```

ALL FALSE:

```
TheDC.TheTable
    .Where(l => l.UserID == TheUserID)
    .All(l => l.FruitName != TheFruitName)
```